# Styling an input type file inside Laravel syntax

Tags: css, laravel

I have an input type file that I want to give a "display: none" to, but It doesn't work when I do it like this.

```
<label class="btn btn-success btn-file">

    {!! Form::file('image', null, ['display'=>'none']) !!}

</label>
```

I could do this through HTML, but my form doesn't allow me to upload files if i don't create my input via Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you are passing is a list of html attributes, `display` is not an existing attribute. You have to set the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute.

```
{!! Form::file('image', null, ['style' => 'display:none']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is array of attributes which will be applied on the HTML element so there is no display attribite, you should use style. Try this:

```
 {!! Form::file('image', ['style'=>'display: none']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work, make a css `class` and put the css to hide like:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and the exact syntax is:

```
Form::file($name, $attributes = array());  // The second param is an array of attributes and you are passing it as null
```

So add that class like:

```
{!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'hidden']) !!}
```

and try again.